# iPhone SDK - Async Behavior?

Tags: iphone, sdk, asynchronous

I have a IBAction that looks like this:

```
self.title = @"Logging in ...";
[MyClass myLongRunningOperation];
```

My Problem is that the view controller title does not get updated until the long running operation has finished. It seems like its put in a queue for later, while my long running operation executes right away.

I'm pretty new to the plattform, so forgive my ignorance here.

Thanks,
-- Felix

Comment: That is how many answers I accept to my questions? Well, I usually don't ask stuff on here if the answer is trivial. This being an exception as I'm a pretty big Obj C noob.

Comment: Sneakyness is suggesting that you go back over the questions you have asked and accept the correct answers.

Comment: Some of them have no correct answer, as of today. See my gmail / ffmpeg questions for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're blocking the UI thread.  Consider using

```
[self performSelectorOnBackgroundThread:@selector(doLongRunningOperation) withObject:nil];
```

You probably really want to read the [Threading Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/Introduction/Introduction.html) at some point.

Comment: Also: http://developer.apple.com/cocoa/managingconcurrency.html (Talks about using NSOperation to manage concurrency rather than dealing with threads directly)